# aabファイルをアップロードしたところ証明書不整合のエラーがでるようになった

Tags: google-play-console

アプリのアップデートを行うために新たなaabファイルをアップロードしました。（今までと同じやり方）
証明書の変更はありません。
どなたかこのようなエラーを経験した方、対処方法をご存知でないでしょうか？
[image: エラー画面]